# How to set debug on flag in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have some code inherited and has the following method that runs code based on if there is a DEBUG_ON flag.

Where can I set this within intellij (or is this an intellij thing)?

```
   private void stuff(String s) {
        if (DEBUG_ON) {
            System.out.println(debug on...);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is this flag? Is there a code to set its value?

Comment: @Vic: it looks like it's a boolean variable in on of tests.  maybe they are just setting it manually?  however, i'm wondering if you can set something up such an as an env variable inside intellij or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with IntelliJ.

Go with the mouse to `DEBUG_ON` and press Ctrl+Click. You will land on the definition of this boolean flag. This is plain old Java. No magic. If the definition is not in a compiled class of a library, but in your source code, you can change the value (true/false).